# What is the largest eigenvalue of this family of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = \{a_{ij}\}$ be an $n \times n$ real valued matrix such that the rows of $A$ sum to 1 and every non-diagonal element $a_{ij} \geq 0$ (with diagonal elements $a_{ii} = -i$). Show that 1 is the largest eigenvalue of $A$ i.e. for any other eigenvalue $\lambda\neq 1$, $Re(\lambda) < 1$.

One can see that 1 is an eigenvalue of $A$ with corresponding eigenvector $ x = (1,1,\dots,1)^{T}$ easily enough but I do not know how to show that 1 is the largest possible eigenvector.  I tried using the fact that for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ and corresponding eigenvector $x = (x_{1},x_{2},\dots x_{n})^{T}$:
$$ \sum_{j}a_{ij}x_j = \lambda x_i $$
Then I tried to use the fact that $\sum_{j \neq i}a_{ij} = i+1$ however I could not complete the proof.

Comment: You can use [Gershgorin circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).

Comment: Thank-you. I guess that for each row $i$ we can define the corresponding Gershgorin disk $D_{i}$ such that if $x \in D_{i}$ then  $-2i-1 \leq Re(x) \leq 1$, thus proving the statement.

Comment: Yes. In fact, since the disks intersect the line $\Re x = 1$ at $x = 1$ only, one has $\Re x < 1$ unless $x = 1$.